# How do I apply GIF in background?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have multiple views on my Constraint Layout. Edit texts and buttons.
I want to use a motion-background. Like objects moving here and there. I have made a GIF for the same.. but how to I apply it to the whole background?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TypeSelection">
```

How do I place a GIF in this? I guess declaring it here is the best option for it to be applied on whole background.

If there is any other way.. please help me.
If you are unable to get my question, let me know.

Comment: I guess the best way is declare an ImageView with match_parent match_parent and load your gif using Glide Library.

Comment: use a library like: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable or https://github.com/Cutta/GifView

Comment: @WelbertMoreira I tried that in a separate app, but the problem is, if I declare image view with  height and width as match_parent, I wont be able to use other buttons and edit texts.

Comment: You can use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout, and put your other views above.

Comment: @WelbertMoreira damn.. yesss.. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @WelbertMoreira can you please explain me how to do this? GIF in background and other views above it.

Comment: @HadiAhmadi actually I don't know how use Github exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned Hadi Ahmadi you need to you use the 3rd party library : `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView` but his answer will not make the GIF as a background it will just make like a header so

Start making a new layout `my_GIF_Layout` and put in it your desired GIF

Put my_GIF_Layout in a  RelativeLayout as your rootLayout and everything will work fine :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/my_GIF_Layout"/>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    ...Your layout code ...

    </RelativeLayout >

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: its done.. with @Hadi Ahmadi's code and your suggestion combined.

Answer (score 3):

by using this library : https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

copy this line in your app level gradle in dependencies block:

```
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.18'
```

[image]

your build.gradle look like this:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.hadi_ahmadi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'

    //gif library added here
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.18'
}
```

then easily add gifView like another views to your layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_gif"
        android:background="@drawable/gif_for_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello!"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gifImageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

your minSdk must be 17 to use this library.
also you can use a lots of method related of this library that you can read about them in above link

let me know if your problem solved or not.

Comment: Getting this error    ERROR: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\deep\AndroidStudioProjects\Gggif\app\build.gradle': 28: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 28, column 25.
       pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.18
                           ^

Comment: minimum SDK is 21 target SDK is 28